# calculating percentage of average in tsql

Tags: t-sql

I have a set of records associated with IDs.  there may be any number of records in this association, with currency values. one of these values is flagged as selected.  I need to calculate an average of all the associated currency values, then take a percentage between this average and the lowest value, grouped by ID.  all the data needed is in one table:

```
input:
table x:  ID, Selected, DollarAmt

output:
view y:  ID, Average, Percentage
```

I'm having problems creating this query(view) and it's driving me nuts.  can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks all.

Comment: did you want to average only the values with selected field = true?  if not, how is the selected field used?

Comment: Please show us some table schema and some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query:

```
select  Id,
    AVG(DollarAmt) Average,
    AVG(DollarAmt)/MIN(DollarAmt) Percentage
from    TableX
group by Id
```

But i´still don´t understand the need of the "Selected" variable in TableX

Regards